# Mongoid Moped could not resolve IP address for... remote MongoDB

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid, moped

I can connect just fine to a local MongoDB, but when I try connecting to either MongoHQ or DotCloud instance using Ruby Mongoid, then I get the above error message.

I'm using Ruby 1.9.3 and Moped 1.5.2.

I can connect to MongoHQ and DotCloud DBs using MongoHub Mac client.

I've tried using irb to debug by doing the following:

```
> require 'Mongoid'
> class Page
>   include Mongoid::Document
>   field :title, type: String
>   end

> Mongoid.sessions = {default: {hosts: ["mongodb://<username>:<password>@troup.mongohq.com:10067"], database: "test"}}

> hello = Page.new
> hello.title = "Try this."
> hello.save
```

This results in the "Could not resolve IP..." error message.

Do you know what I'm missing. Or any tips for debugging this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

```
Mongoid.sessions = {default: {hosts: ["mongodb://<username>:<password>@troup.mongohq.com:10067"], database: "test"}}
```

to and give your username and password below

```
Mongoid.sessions = {default: {uri: ["mongodb://<username>:<password>@troup.mongohq.com:10067/test"]}}
```

if you are going to hosts, in that uri hosts is `troup.mongohq.com:10067` port is 10067, database test and for authentication username and password...

Comment: Thanks - that helped! I found I had to remove the enclosing array brackets "[...]", then that worked on my local environment.

Comment: So, there seemed to be three things causing related errors:  1) I should have been using uri settings instead of hosts - as abhas showed.  2) I needed to ensure I was passing a user who had been assigned against the DB I was trying to access. Stupid, I know, but I was trying to just use the default root user that DotCloud had created for me.  3) DotCloud defaults to ruby 1.9.2, but Moped / Mongoid requires 1.9.3 to work properly. Once I update this in my dotcloud.yml file and pushed up, it all work.